# Center a type text input

Tags: html, css

I want to center these text boxes and space them.
And what I did does not work.
This is my code;
[HTMl Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXffF.png)

[CSS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8IoL.png)

[The Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLVN2.png)

Comment: Please indicate your code in text. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Alex. If you post your actual code instead of images, it will make it much easier for anyone to help you. Take a moment to read though this article about how to post code examples: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please use the snippet functionality to add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: verdana;
}

#ToDo
{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.title
{
    text-align: center;
}
#Done
{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.in
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
}
.box
{
    background: #444;
    padding: 0;
    width: 40%;
}
.inBox
{
    background: #bbb;
}
#container
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background: #03a9f4;
    flex-wrap: all;
    padding: 50px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <p id="by">by Me</p>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="inBox">
                <h2 id="ToDo">To Do</h2>
            </div>
            <label for="task"></label>
            <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter Task">
            <label for="task"></label>
            <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter Task">
            <label for="task"></label>
            <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter Task">
            <label for="task"></label>
            <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter Task">
            <label for="task"></label>
            <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter Task">
            <label for="task"></label>
            <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter Task">
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="inBox">
                <h2 id="ToDo">Done</h2>
            </div>
            <label for="task"></label>
            <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter Task">
            <label for="task"></label>
            <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter Task">
            <label for="task"></label>
            <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter Task">
            <label for="task"></label>
            <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter Task">
            <label for="task"></label>
            <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter Task">
            <label for="task"></label>
            <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter Task">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for you, I used normal HTML and CSS for this nothing special just flexbox for centering and made it responsive by fixing the widths by percentages.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
body{
    background: cadetblue;

}
.title{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.container{
    width: 1100px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.boxes{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
.box{
    width:450px;
    background: darksalmon;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box_title{
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background: cadetblue;
    border: 3px black solid;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
}
.inputs{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To-do lista</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h1 class="title__text">To Do List</h1>
        <p class="title__para">by Fluierici</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="boxes">  
            <div class="box">
                <div class="inbox">
                    <h2 class="box_title">To Do</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="inputs">
                    <label for="task"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter task">
                    <label for="task"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter task">
                    <label for="task"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter task">
                    <label for="task"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter task">
                    <label for="task"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter task">
                    <label for="task"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter task">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <div class="inbox">
                    <h2 class="box_title">Done</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="inputs">
                    <label for="task"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter task">
                    <label for="task"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter task">
                    <label for="task"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter task">
                    <label for="task"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter task">
                    <label for="task"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter task">
                    <label for="task"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="in" placeholder="Enter task">
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is code for u

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.